# ServiceStack Validation - method missing

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to implement validation and in reading:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation

I see this method being used.  It doesn't seem to be on the Funq container, what am I missing?

```
//This method scans the assembly for validators
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(UserValidator).Assembly);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think a method is missing in ServiceStack it's most likely an extension method. [RegisterValidators()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Validation/ValidationFeature.cs#L97) is an extension method in the **ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Validation** namespace.

You should consider using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) as there as it eliminates a whole class of issues with C# development including locating methods, auto including namespaces, auto referencing of dlls, etc.

Otherwise if for some reason you want to continue without ReSharper you can use the `T` short-cut looking in the [ServiceStack GitHub Repo](http://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) which helps find files, otherwise use `Ctrl+Shift+F` to do a solution-wide text search in a local fork of ServiceStack.